# Where function passed as UnmanagedFunctionPointer to C is executed?

Tags: c#, .net, c, interop, unmanaged

In C, there is a function that accepts a pointer to a function to perform comparison:

```
[DllImport("mylibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int set_compare(IntPtr id, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]CompareFunction cmp);
```

In C#, a delegate is passed to the C function:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int CompareFunction(ref IntPtr left, ref IntPtr right);
```

Currently, I accept `Func<T,T,int> comparer` in a constructor of a generic class and convert it to the delegate. "mylibrary.dll" owns data, managed C# library knows how to convert pointers to `T` and then compare `T`s.

```
//.in ctor 
CompareFunction cmpFunc = (ref IntPtr left, ref IntPtr  right) => {
                    var l = GenericFromPointer<T>(left);
                    var r = GenericFromPointer<T>(right);
                    return comparer(l, r);
                };
```

I also have an option to write a CompareFunction in C for most important data types that are used in 90%+ cases, but I hope to avoid modifications to the native library.

The question is, when setting the compare function with P/Invoke, does every subsequent call to that function from C code incurs marshaling overheads, or the delegate is called from C as if it was initially written in C?

I imagine that, when compiled, the delegate is a sequence of machine instructions in memory, but do not understand if/why C code would need to ask .NET to make the actual comparison, instead of just executing these instructions in place?

I am mostly interested in better understanding how interop works. However, this delegate is used for binary search on big data sets, and if every subsequent call has some overheads as a single P/Invoke, rewriting comparers in native C could be a good option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I imagine that, when compiled, the delegate is a sequence of machine instructions in memory, but do not understand if/why C code would need to ask .NET to make the actual comparison, instead of just executing these instructions in place?

I guess you're a bit confused about how .NET works. C doesn't *ask* .NET to execute code.

First, your lambda is turned into a compiler-generated class instance (because you're closing over the `comparer` variable), and then a delegate to a method of this class is used. And it's an instance method since your lambda is a closure.

A delegate is similar to a function pointer. So, like you say, it points to executable code. Whether this code is generated from a C source or a .NET source is irrelevant *at this point*.

It's in the interop case when this starts to matter. P/Invoke won't pass your delegate as-is as a function pointer to C code. It will pass a function pointer to a *thunk* which calls the delegate. Visual Studio will display this as a *[Native to Managed Transition]* stack frame. This is needed for different reasons such as marshaling or passing additional parameters (like the instance of the class backing your lambda for instance).

As to the performance considerations of this, here's what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717435.aspx) says, quite obviously:

> Thunking. Regardless of the interoperability technique used, special transition sequences, which are known as thunks, are required each time a managed function calls an native function, and vice-versa. Because thunking contributes to the overall time that it takes to interoperate between managed code and native code, **the accumulation of these transitions can negatively affect performance**.

So, if your code requires a lot of transitions between managed and native code, you should get better performance by doing your comparisons on the C side if possible, so that you avoid the transitions.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed to know - thunking.

Comment: If I write in C functions like `compare_ints`, `compare_doubles`, but then do the resolution in C# and pass pointers to these *native* functions to `set_compare`, will that avoid thunking? Or I need to pass a flag/enum to C and do resolution to actual implementation inside C?

Comment: If you have direct pointers to these native functions (from [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) for instance), and if you pass them as `IntPtr` to `set_compare`, then it'll avoid thunking altogether because .NET won't be involved at all (you may need two overloads for `set_compare` on the .NET side if you also want to pass lambdas though). I *suppose* you may get thunking if you import `compare_ints` as a delegate and then pass that delegate to `set_compare` - but I'm not sure. That's a **very** interesting question, worth investigating.